# For which natural numbers $N$ does $D(N)=2N-\sigma_{1}(N) \mid N$ hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma_{1}(N)$ denote the sum of the divisors of the natural number $N$.

Here is my question:

> For which natural numbers $N$ does $2N-\sigma(N)= D(N) \mid N$ hold?

$D(N)$ is the [**deficiency**](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $N$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

When $N=p$ is **<s>prime</s>** an odd prime, then
$$D(N)=D(p)=2p-\sigma(p)=2p-(p+1)=p-1$$
which *does not divide* $N=p$. (In fact, $\gcd(N, D(N))=\gcd(p,p-1)=1$.)

When $N=p^k$ is **<s>a prime power</s>** an odd prime power, then
$$D(N)=D(p^k)=2{p^k}-\sigma(p^k)=2{p^k}-\left(1 + p + \ldots + p^k\right)={p^k}-\sigma(p^{k-1}).$$
Now, since $\gcd(p,\sigma(p^{k-1}))=1$, then $\gcd(p^k,\sigma(p^{k-1}))=1$.  Consequently, $$\gcd(N,D(N))=\gcd({p^k},{p^k}-\sigma(p^{k-1}))=1.$$
It follows that ${p^k}-\sigma(p^{k-1})=D(N) \nmid N$.

**ADDED SEPTEMBER 26 2016**

*OOPS*.  When $N=2^r$ and $r \geq 0$, then $D(N)=2N-\sigma(N)=2^{r+1}-\frac{2^{r+1} - 1}{2 - 1}=1$.  Thus, for $N=2^r$ and $r \geq 0$, $D(N) \mid N$.

Which leads me to ask:

> Is $N=2^r$ for $r \geq 0$ the only (infinite) family of natural numbers satisfying $2N-\sigma(N)=D(N) \mid N$?

At this point, it seems hard to generalize to $\omega(N) \geq 2$, where $\omega(N)$ is the *number of distinct prime factors* of $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only considering numbers $n$ for which $2n-\sigma(n)>0$, they are tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A271816), where they are called "deficient-perfect numbers." There are plenty of numbers listed there that aren't powers of 2. It doesn't say whether there are infinitely many, but there are links to some references – maybe you could check them out, and report your findings back to us. It does say,

"If $2^{k+1} + 2^t - 1$ is an odd prime and $t \le k$, then $n = 2^k(2^{k+1} + 2^t - 1)$ is deficient-perfect with $2n - \sigma(n) = 2^t$. In fact, these are the only terms with two distinct prime factors."

If you allow abundant numbers, too, well, they're probably tabulated at OEIS as well. I didn't check.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that OEIS sequence, Gerry!  I was actually searching for papers on deficient-perfect (and near-perfect) numbers in Google earlier, and Min Tang, et. al's papers were among those that came up.  Sadly, I don't have access to their papers currently.  I will e-mail Professor Min Tang to ask for a copy.